# Zurb 6.4.0 - where did the large-pull-3 go?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation-6

I am using zurb foundation 6.3.4 and uses large-pull and large-push to reorder two rows of content on big screens.

Tried to update to 6.4.0, and these are gone! The hardworking zurb-gang has not yet updated the docs completely, and the migration notes are limited. (No nagging here; I know how much time it takes to keep docs up to date.)

Someone that knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the large-push-9 and large-pull-3 in a minimal adaptation:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
    <div class="row">
      <article class="large-3 medium-12 columns large-push-9">
         <!---content sidebar-->
      </article>
      <article class="large-9 medium-12 large-pull-3 columns">
         <!---maincontent-->
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
    @media print, screen and (min-width: 64em) {
      .large-push-9 {
      position: relative;
      left: 75%; }
      .large-pull-3 {
        position: relative;
        left: -25%; }
    }
</style>
```

It fixed my problem, but anyone with a "real" answer, i.e. how to use zurbs grid-container properly, might want to chime in.